# is it possible to comment or share a link on box_count facebook plugin and how?

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

there is an app on a facebook contest, every contestant has a virtual link pointing to some information that other users may like. The winner is the one with the most likes in his link after two weeks. The app itself uses the iframe facebook like button plugin with the box_count layout, therefore the contestants could gather only "likes" and not "shares" or "comments" on their link. The point is that one or two contestants, after the analyzation of "like" types, seems to have a lot of shares and comments too. Is there any way for him to achieve that or he hacked something??

Thanks in advance,
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use the like button in this fashion.  https://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php  See #5 specifically.  You will need to make your own storage system for votes.